# Is there a way to see the order in which attendees RSVP'd as attending an event?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I'm an admin of a fairly large group, but this particular event is severely space limited, so I've said that only the first 12 people that RSVP will be able to come. Normally, this isn't a problem but sometimes people bring friends that aren't part of the group, so they can't actually RSVP on it.

This means I have to manually track how many people are coming and in what order they did it so I can fairly decide who actually gets to come. It would be pretty helpful if there was an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guaranteed way to do this via Facebook, unfortunately.

You can infer some things about RSVP order via the guest list, but you have to realize a few things:

1. This is unreliable, since Facebook has made no promise that it works this way (this is simply my own observation), and
2. Facebook changes how its site works *all the time*. There is no guarantee on how long this will be true.

If you click to see who is "Going" on an event, it will list people (as applicable) in the following order:

1. You
2. Facebook friends marked as "Close friends", in RSVP order
3. Facebook friends, in RSVP order
4. Facebook friends marked as "Acquaintances", in RSVP order
5. People you are not friends with, in RSVP order

If it is very important to know the true, reliable RSVP order, and you won't be able to check often enough to ensure that you catch it at 12 people, you are probably better off using a different tool.

Comment: My "solution" is to screenshot the guest list often, that will mostly give me an overview of the order of RSVP's